# Thymeleaf: Generate URL for action in controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I started learning Spring framework and before Spring I used Laravel. In Laravel we had various helpers for generating urls, for example:

```
<a href="{{ action('MyController@someAction') }}">Some url</a>
```

Is there anything similar in Thymeleaf, basically I want to generate an url which will point to some action in controller so if I change the mapping of the controller the url will change for all anchor tags.

Comment: From the thymeleaf documentation, it seems that the templates map urls based on `@RequestMapping` paths.  I don't believe there is functionality to bind the controller methods themselves.  https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/standardurlsyntax.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a library present for spring boot framework. Which you need to add in your project in order to generate link dynamically. The gradle dependency of this library is given below.

```
compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas:2.1.4.RELEASE'
```

I am assuming your build system is gradle but if you are using maven then please use below syntax.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

After than you can generate link dynamically as below.

```
WebMvcLinkBuilder.linkTo(MyController.class).slash("someAction").withSelfRel().getHref();
```

Answer (score -2):

Thymeleaf and Spring Boot have very Good Relation.
Create Spring Boot App from [Spring-initializr](http://start.spring.io/)
Add the Following dependency in your Spring Boot pom.xml

```
spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf
```

WelcomeController.java

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    // inject via application.properties
    @Value("${welcome.message:test}")
    private String message = "Hello World";

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("message", this.message);
        return "welcome";
    }

}
```

Add the Following in your welcome.html
src/main/resources/templates/welcome.html

Add HTML defination :

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
```

Add into Body.

```
<span th:text="'Message: ' + ${message}"></span>
```

Table view

```
<tbody>
    <tr th:each="student: ${students}">
      <td> <a th:href="${student.id}"><span  th:text="${student.name}"></span> </a></td>

    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

And Thats All

Comment: How is this related to my question. I want to know how to dynamically create url which points to MyController@someAction using thymeleaf

Comment: <a th:href="@{/student/id}">